# Send documents to printer without waiting for Vista to handle queue

Tags: windows-vista, printer, print-server, queue

I got a print server on our old printer. Vista has its own queue which presents a problem.

I want to bypass this queue and send everything straight away to the printer so the print server deals with the queue and not Vista.

Problem is when a second document is being printed from the same computer after first one. Vista is still waiting for info on finishing the first job even 5 minutes after it was REALLY finished.

How do I get it so that I can send straight to the print server and not have Vista slow things down by trying to handle the queue itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is when a second document is being printed from the same computer after first one. Vista is still waiting for info on finishing the first job even 5 minutes after it was REALLY finished.

So your real problem is that the print server doesn't send back information that the job has been completed, not that Vista has a print *queue*.

I suggest looking up the definition of what a "queue" is (hint: it's FIFO). Vista is doing its job, the print server should be making information available to the print spooler regarding the state of the printed jobs.

Configure your print server.

Answer (score 0):

In Printer Properties, under Printer Options there should be a "Print directly to the printer" setting.

Comment: when i check this box, and go to some application and try to print => the dialogue of "printing copy 1 of 1" is there like for 5 minutes .. it is still waiting for info from the printer i guess

Answer (score -1):

[LPR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon_protocol) may be a solution

some info here:

http://www.vistax64.com/vista-print-fax-scan/122295-how-do-you-install-lpr-printing-components-win-vista.html

Comment: I tried to install it but it still doesn't send all document straight to print server. it's sending them one by one

Comment: Have you configured the port that the print server is installed on as LPR?